# How to retrieve UIImage from particular folder in document directory in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiimage

I have used the below function to store images locally in a folder created in document directory

```
NSError *error;
NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

// FOR STORING IMAGE INTO FOLDER CREATED IN DOCUMENT DIRECTORY

NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/ImagesFolder"];    
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];

NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image);
NSString* incrementedImgStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image%d.png",delegate.dirCountImages];
NSString* fullPathToFile2 = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:incrementedImgStr];
[imageData writeToFile:fullPathToFile2 atomically:NO];
```

However how do i retrieve images from that particular folder in document directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(NSMutableArray*)getPhotoFileNames:(NSString*)parentFolderName
{
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0], parentFolderName];

NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:nil];   
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [dirContents objectEnumerator];
id fileName;
NSMutableArray *fileArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
while (fileName = [enumerator nextObject]) 
{
    NSString *fullFilePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    NSRange textRangeJpg = [[fileName lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[@".png" lowercaseString]];

    if (textRangeJpg.location != NSNotFound) 
    {
        UIImage     *originalImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullFilePath];
        [fileArray addObject:originalImage];
    }
}
return fileArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to have the full path and use this method. `[[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile: <#path#>]` remember to release the image after if you are not using ARC.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,100,100)];
imageView.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:myImage];

[myView addSubview:imageView];
```

or see that link http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/23840-placing-image-url-image-view.html

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help you.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
documentsDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Images"];
documentsDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image.png"];
[cell.songImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:documentsDirectory]];
```